# Kendo-Ui angular 2 grid control with check boxes for first column

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

how to add check box for first column of kendo UI angular2 grid? and how to retrive if the data is checked or not for each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found answer to this quesion.
add following code to grid template.

```
<kendo-grid-column field="Select" width="50">
                            <template kendoCellTemplate kendoHeaderTemplate let-dataItem>
                                <input type="checkbox" />
                            </template>
                        </kendo-grid-column>
```

Comment: I suppose you have a checkbox for each row... When you click on this header cheackbox, what is your approach to update the rows?

Comment: this is an old comment. header cell is tricky. if it is paged, do you expect to check all items or only current page items? in my case, i had to check all items. more on header checkbox can be found here. [check-allcheckboxkendo](https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-place-%27check-all%27-checkbox-in-kendo-grid-column-template)